# Transfer of Packets in Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark

I am using Windows 10 based PC in Access Point(HotSpot) mode and attached two Wi-Fi clients and transferring TCP packets between them. Using wireshark i am monitoring packets being sent. I am unable to trace TCP packets does this mean that packets in Wi-Fi are directly routed between two clients? without router being involved?

Is there a way where i could see all the packets on wireshark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all traffic still goes via the hotspot.  You would need to set your network up in ad-hoc mode for it to bypass the AP.

Comment: why am i unable to see the packets then? Can we change settings and see all the packets on wireshark?

Comment: How can i see TCP packets on wireshark running on Windows 10 in AP mode.